# Как сделать подобное javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая функция:

```
create('arg')
```

В нее передаются аргументы,а можно как-нибудь сделать подобное:

```
create('arg').css({
//Тут должны быть css стили
})
.destroy(); //Удаление
```

И как принимать подобное?

Comment: конкретизируйте

Comment: Нужно вызывать функцию передавая аргументы,а потом еще раз через .css(Тут тоже аргументы в виде стилей)

Comment: ну какого ответа вы ждете тут? я допустим ничего не понял, что требуется)

Comment: Я видел вот такое в библиотеке,как это реализовать? nano('tag .class')
 .css({
  'background' : 'red',
  'color' : 'blue'
 })
 .appendTo('body')
 .find('code')
 .destroy();

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z3uL6pk0/

Comment: почему бы вам не посмотреть на исходный код библиотеки?

Comment: Просто там многовато кода и я немного не понимаю что именно за это отвечает https://github.com/theshock/nanojs/blob/master/atom.js

Comment: Судя по вопросу вам нужна функция, возвращающая jquery объект. Это не сложно и можно в одну короткую строчку уместить: `let create=arg=>$()`, но в чём сокральный смысл вашей задумки?

Comment: А без jquery можно такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как сделать подобное javascript?
>
> create('arg').css({
> //Тут должны быть css стили
> })
> .destroy(); //Удаление

Вот такой вариант:

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Сама функция с эффектом chaining methods
// Вызов: create('tag .class #id') или create('tag .class') 
// или create('tag  #id') без класса
function create(args) {
  // Два пробела если не хотите class, а только id
  // 
  [this.tag, this.className, this.id] = args.split(' ')
  // Создание элемента
  this.elem = document.createElement(this.tag)
  if (this.className) { // 
    this.elem.className = this.className.replace(/\./, '')
  }
  if (this.id) { // 
    this.elem.id = this.id.replace(/\#/, '')
  }
  // appendTo 
  this.appendTo = function(s) {
    document.querySelector(s).appendChild(this.elem);
    return this;
  }
  // css function
  this.css = function({ ...args
  } = {}) {
    var s = ''
    Object.keys(args).forEach(function(v) {
      s += `${v}:${args[v]};`
    })
    this.elem.style = s
    return this;
  }
  // find element
  this.find = function(needle) {
    this.found = this.elem.parentNode.querySelectorAll(needle)
    return this
  }
  // destory if has found then found otherwise 
  this.destroy = function() {
    if (this.found && this.found.length > 0) {
      this.found.forEach(function(v, i) {
        this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(v)
      })

      //this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(this.found)
    } else
      this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(this.elem)
    return this
  }
  // text function....
  this.text = function(t) {
    this.elem.innerText = t
    return this
  }
  return this;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Использование
create('div .added')
  .css({
    'border': '3px solid black',
    'color': 'yellow',
    'margin': '1px',
    'padding': '.6em'
  })
  .text('<script>console.log("Something to say?")<\/script>')
  .appendTo('.body')
  .find('span.added') // 
  .destroy() // Удалит найденые объекты или сам элемент если не было поиска
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Использование
create('div .done')
.css({'margin-top':'5px', 'border':'3px dotted green', 'float':'right'})
.appendTo('.body')
```

```css
.added {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.done {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <!-------- Some -------->
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
</span>

  <span class="added">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. А не лучше ли реализовать методы через прототипы?

Comment: Это очень круто,спасибо большое)

Comment: А можно как-то сделать так,чтобы обращение было через name.create,т.е чтобы функции были в массиве? Я сделал,но выдает ошибку Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined. И еще не работает find без create(). Я очень обнаглевший) Но я уже очень благодарен